# How to use a directive to add an attribute before this attribute is used by another module?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular-directive

I have added a module that let me put a mask on an input.

This module works with the attribute 'textMask' with the value of the mask and options (ex.: `[textMask]="{mask: dateMask, placeholderChar: '\u2000', keepCharPositions: true}"` and code behind: `public dateMask = [/[0-3]/, /\d/, "/", /[0-1]/, /\d/, "/", /[12]/, /[09]/, /\d/, /\d/];` for a french date mask).

Rather than add this mask to every date input and code behind of every components, I'd prefer to make a directive that add the attribute to every date inputs.

So, I did this:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: 'input[matDatepicker]'
})
export class DateMaskDirective {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef<HTMLElement>, private renderer: Renderer) {
    this.renderer.setElementAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, '[textMask]', '{ mask: [/[0-3]/, /\d/, "/", /[0-1]/, /\d/, "/", /[12]/, /[09]/, /\d/, /\d/], placeholderChar: "\u2000", keepCharPositions: true }');
  }
}
```

The problem is, even if the attribute is added, it is not interpreted by the mask module. Is it a problem of priority? How can I fix that?

Link to the mask module: https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/tree/master/angular2#readme

**EDIT**

I tried Daniel Hilgarth's solution (derive mask directive) like so:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { MaskedInputDirective, TextMaskConfig } from 'angular2-text-mask';

@Directive({
  selector: 'input[matDatepicker]'
})
export class DateMaskDirective extends MaskedInputDirective {
  public textMaskConfig: TextMaskConfig = {
    mask: [/[0-3]/, /\d/, "/", /[0-1]/, /\d/, "/", /[12]/, /[09]/, /\d/, /\d/],
    guide: true,
    placeholderChar: '\u2000',
    keepCharPositions: true,
    showMask: true
  }

  constructor(private el: ElementRef<any>, private renderer: Renderer2, _compositionMode: boolean) {
    super(renderer, el, _compositionMode);
  }
}
```

But I get the following Angular error:

```
ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[DateMaskDirective -> Boolean]:
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[DateMaskDirective -> Boolean]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for Boolean!
    at NullInjector.push../ node_modules /@angular/core/fesm5 / core.js.NullInjector.get(core.js: 691)
    at resolveToken(core.js: 928)
    at tryResolveToken(core.js: 872)
    at StaticInjector.push../ node_modules /@angular/core/fesm5 / core.js.StaticInjector.get(core.js: 769)
    at resolveToken(core.js: 928)
    at tryResolveToken(core.js: 872)
    at StaticInjector.push../ node_modules /@angular/core/fesm5 / core.js.StaticInjector.get(core.js: 769)
    at resolveNgModuleDep(core.js: 17435)
    at NgModuleRef_.push../ node_modules /@angular/core/fesm5 / core.js.NgModuleRef_.get(core.js: 18124)
    at resolveDep(core.js: 18495)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not an attribute. It's a directive of it's own.
One possible solution would be to derive your directive from their directive.

Try something like this (untested, but important is the decorator on the boolean constructor parameter):

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { MaskedInputDirective, TextMaskConfig } from 'angular2-text-mask';

@Directive({
  selector: 'input[matDatepicker]'
})
export class DateMaskDirective extends MaskedInputDirective {
  public textMaskConfig: TextMaskConfig = {
    mask: [/[0-3]/, /\d/, "/", /[0-1]/, /\d/, "/", /[12]/, /[09]/, /\d/, /\d/],
    guide: true,
    placeholderChar: '\u2000',
    keepCharPositions: true,
    showMask: true
  }

  constructor(private el: ElementRef<any>, private renderer: Renderer2, @Optional() @Inject(COMPOSITION_BUFFER_MODE) _compositionMode: boolean) {
    super(renderer, el, _compositionMode);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant (maybe I was not clear). It's a directive based on an attribute. Can I not prioritize my directive to make it happen first, so that it apply the attribute that the mask module will then be able to use to set up the mask?

Comment: It's *not* an attribute. That's what I am saying.

Comment: Well, on the template, this is actually an attribute. I use [] to make it dynamic and use the code behind, but I could use `textMask="{mask: [/[0-3]/, /\d/, "/", /[0-1]/, /\d/, "/", /[12]/, /[09]/, /\d/, /\d/], placeholderChar: '\u2000', keepCharPositions: true}"` and it would work too. I just want to use a directive to modify my template before the mask directive is used.

Comment: I tried your solution to derive the mask directive, but I got a `StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[DateMaskDirective -> Boolean]` error. I updated my question with more details on this.

Comment: The problem is: The "code" in the .html file of your component is parsed by Angular and results in a ngfactory class. This class will then be used to create the actual component instance. So, again: It's not an attribute on a HTML DOM element. It's just text that does look like an attribute. Maybe it becomes more obvious when you think about what happens when you enable AOT. In that case, the ngfactory class is created at build time, so it should be obvious that no attribute that you add at runtime will have any effect here.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations and for the code but it does not work. There are no errors but the input does not receive the mask.

Comment: The `ng-reflect-text-mask-config` attribute that should ba added isn't added to the element. I added this line: `el.nativeElement.classList.add("test");` to be sure the selector match and `test` is indeed added to the class list.